# Runtime error with scanners

Tags: java

Why does my code have a runtime error?(java)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentID
{
    static int gradeLevel;
    static int id;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("---Student ID---");
        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        String firstName = keyboard.next();
        System.out.print("\nEnter your last name: ");
        String lastName = keyboard.next();
        System.out.print("\nEnter your grade level: ");
        gradeLevel = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\nEnter your id: ");
        id = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\nThe text for your student id is:");
        String result = getIDText(firstName, lastName, gradeLevel, id);
        System.out.print(result);
    }

    public static String getIDText(
        String firstName, 
        String lastName, 
        int gradeLevel, 
        int id)
    {
        String result = 
            "\n\nName: " + lastName + ", " + firstName + 
            "\nGrade: " + gradeLevel +
            "\nID: " + id;
        return result;
    }
}
```

I can enter my my data just fine, but after type in my ID and press enter, my program crashes saying i have an error at `id = keyboard.nextInt();`

My **error** is this:

```
java.util.InputMismatchException at
java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864) at
java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485) at
java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117) at
java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076) at
StudentID.main(StudentID.java:18)
```

Comment: What is this runtime error?

Comment: @JacekCz  java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at StudentID.main(StudentID.java:18)

Comment: So the error code simply says it cannot parse what you have inputted to an integer. Your option is to change input to a string and then parse it in a try catch block yourself. And if it fails, you ask user to input that ID again.

Comment: because you have entered sth instead of `int` in your console

Comment: send your input so that i can send the answer

Comment: Which is line 18 ?

Comment: @Stewart this is definetly `id = keyboard.nextInt();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code works fine in case you print **integer** value for **ID**. If you print `String` value, like e.g. `aaa`, you get this `java.util.InputMismatchException`. If you would like to check incorrect data, you have to read always `String` an then in the code *manually* convert it.

***P.S.*** You should close `Scanner` isntance somehwere: `keyboard.close()`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to resolve this:
1. use keyboard.nextLine() instead of keyboard.next if your string input has spaces in between as the input is considered only till it encounters first space.
2. if you want to use keyboard.next() only, the check whether the input is int when you want for e.g:

```
    if(keyboard.hasNextInt()) 
{
   id = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```